# How to Pass multiple parameter in Multivalue Converter Over WPF DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, imultivalueconverter, multiparameter

I'm having four `int` Property `ProOne`, `ProTwo`, `ProThree` and `ProFour`

I have to Implement the Boolean Logic `((ProOne == ProTwo) || (ProThree == ProFour))` in the Multivalue Converter namely `VisibilityCheckConverter`. Based on the Logic the Multivalue Converter `VisibilityCheckConverter` returns `True` or `False`.

Now I need to pass the four properties to the Converter over DataTrigger, Based on the Value, I have to change the Buttons Visibility to Visible

How does one write the a **DataTrigger using Multivalue Converter with multiple parameters**?

Sample Piece of XAML Code:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Property="{Binding , Converter={StaticResource VisibilityCheckConverter,ConverterParameter=ProOne ProTwo ProThree ProFour}}" Value="true">
        <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Can you show some code so we can help.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I posted the sample piece of XAML code. Kindly assist me...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilityCheckConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ProOne" />
                <Binding Path="ProTwo" />
                <Binding Path="ProThree" />
                <Binding Path="ProFour" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter TargetName="Button" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```